# access 2007 query and c# datatable show different output

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, oledb

I have the below query in access 2007 which gave me correct results using the sql design view of access..

```
  SELECT B1.LAYER_TYPE,
  B1.LAYER_NAME AS LAYER_NAME,
  B2.LAYER_NAME AS RELATED_LAYER_NAME,
  B3.LAYER_NAME AS RELATED_LAYER2_NAME,
  C.RULE_NAME
  FROM (((NCS_RULES_RELATIONS AS A
  LEFT JOIN NCS_LAYERS AS B1 ON A.LAYER_ID = B1.LAYER_ID)
  LEFT JOIN NCS_LAYERS AS B2 ON A.RELTD_LAYER_ID = B2.LAYER_ID)
  LEFT JOIN NCS_LAYERS AS B3 ON A.RELTD_LAYER2_ID = B3.LAYER_ID)
  LEFT JOIN NCS_RULES AS C ON A.RULE_ID = C.RULE_ID
  ORDER BY B1.LAYER_TYPE;
```

the results are below :

[image: query results in access]

but when i try to get the results to a datatable using `c#` and `oledbconnection` to access, the RULE_NAME field value for the last row shows weird results(see pic below).

[image: from visualstudio]

my code for retrieving table is below:

```
public DataTable GetTable(string strSelectSQL)
        {
            if (this.con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            IDbCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = strSelectSQL;
            command.Connection = con;

            IDbDataAdapter da = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = command;
            da.Fill(ds);

            dt = ds.Tables[0];

            con.Close();
            return dt;

        }
```

can somebody help me with this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems everything is fine. My guess you have multiline value in `Rule_name field` like this: `AnnoFromLine\n\rDimOnLine`. Datagridview displaying multiline value as you can see and sql design view diplaying just first line.